# Why do globally known fast food (KFC, McDonalds, etc) mostly sell chicken?

Tags: chicken

What is with chicken that it is used most of the time as the "main" product of most fast foods, specially in the US? Is chicken easier to prepare? to cook? What is with chicken?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about food in general, but not about its preparation or solving an actual problem.

Comment: Since when did McDonald's "mostly sell chicken"?

Comment: I think of McDonald's as a company that sells french fries mostly...

Comment: Interesting. I am jewish and only eat kosher, so this question doesn't apply, but growing up, the only item I heard of from McDonalds was a Big Mac, which is definitely NOT chicken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a global view, chicken is the meat product least likely to be objectionable to various sub-groups (other than vegetarian/vegan sub-groups.) Beef and pork are taboo foods for various religions and this will presumably alter the menu in locations where those religions predominate. I'm presently not aware of any group which eats meat that deems chicken unsuitable.

KFC, previously known as "Kentucky Fried Chicken" will, of course, be chicken-centric. They have other sub-brands (*i.e.* Taco Bell) which sell other meats.

Chicken is hardly the predominant meat product in USA McDonalds. They sell mostly ground beef patties.

Comment: The question is totally whacky and should be closed or deleted.  But it's a fascinating/bizarre point that "McDonalds" is actually the world's biggest seller of chicken.  (They sell far more beef/etc than chicken - but it works out that they are the world's biggest seller of chicken!)  (A similar astounding statistic is that Coca Cola are the world's biggest purchasor (by far) of *vanilla*, this for their relative tiny "vanilla coke" line.)

Comment: It's the same for McDonalds in Europe. In all European countries where I went to a McDonalds, the menu was mainly the same one, with a focus on beef.

Comment: @Fattie: The vanilla part is less surprising when you realize it's _natural_ vanilla. A lot of products with "vanilla flavor" use the far cheaper chemicals Methyl vanillin and/or Ethyl vanillin.

Answer (score 12):

Your premise is false: while KFC mostly sells chicken (because they are a chicken restaurant), other fast food providers, including McDonalds, do not predominantly sell chicken (see [this article](https://spoonuniversity.com/lifestyle/mcdonalds-most-popular-items) listing the top 10 most popular items at McDonalds in the US, only one of which contains chicken).

For instance, [this article](http://uk.businessinsider.com/the-20-most-successful-fast-food-chains-in-america-2015-8/#1-mcdonalds-22220) lists the top 20 fast food chains in the US, of which only numbers 8 (Chick-fil-A) and 11 (KFC) serve chicken as their 'main' products.

Comment: Menus do vary by country, which might be what made the OP (profile says Philippines) think McDonald's is mainly a chicken place. It looks like they do still have hamburgers in the Philippines, but they might not be thought of as the canonical McDonald's food the way they are in the US.

Comment: Also, McDonald's seems to sell whole pieces of fried chicken in the Philippines, whereas that is something that only "chicken places" (KFC, Popeye's, Church's - not Chick-fil-A) have in the US.

Comment: McDonalds India also has a quite chicken-centric menu due to beef being taboo for Hindus.